# What's the spliting field of $x^8-1$ over $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: field-theory

> What's the spliting field of $x^8-1$  over $\mathbb Q$ ?

I did:

$$x:=r\text{cis}(\theta)\\
x^8=r^8\text{cis}(8\theta)\\ 
\\r=1\\
\theta=\frac{2\pi k}{8}=\frac{\pi k}{4}\quad k\in\{0,...,7\}$$

$\implies$ the roots are: $\{1,\text{cis}(\pi/4),\text{cis}(\pi/2),..\}$

$\implies$ the spliting field is [$\mathbb Q(\text{cis}(\pi/4))$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cis(pi%2F4))

But in my notebook the answer is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,i)$, maybe mistake?

Comment: ... or an isomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The polynomial factors over $\mathbb{Q}$ as
$$
(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)
$$
and over $\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
x^4+1=(x^2-\sqrt{2}\,x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}\,x+1)
$$
The roots of $x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1$ are
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}\pm i\sqrt{2}}{2}
$$
and the roots of $x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1$ are
$$
\frac{-\sqrt{2}\pm i\sqrt{2}}{2}
$$
Clearly $\sqrt{2}$ belongs to the splitting field, being the sum of the roots of $x^2-\sqrt{2}+1$ and also $i$ belongs to it, being a root of $x^2+1$.

Therefore $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$ is contained in the splitting field, but clearly it contains all the roots of $x^8-1$.

Your solution is good as well, of course: there's no unique way to write the splitting field.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\zeta=e^{\pi i/4}=\frac12(1+i)\sqrt 2$. What does that make
$\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$? What about $\zeta+\zeta^3$?